# WMI Query on a non english system

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, culture

i have to query the WMI-Api on a german and an english computer. But on the different systems, there are different results.

For example:

I have to query "Msvm_ComputerSystem". There is a property named "Caption". On the english computer the result is "Virtual Machine" an on a german computer the result is "Virtueller Computer".

How can i force the language to en-us?

Comment: Can you add why this is important? What do you want to do with the value rather than displaying it to the user?

Comment: I have to write some queries to query the state of an hyper-v vm. The problem is: i have to work with the result in my c# code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it will work, but it is worth trying. Before executing the query, change the culture of the current thread to [`CultureInfo.Invariant`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.Invariant;
```